# Deleting vertices in R

Tags: r, igraph

I am using igraph and trying to delete few vertices.When I try to delete vertex 77, I see vertex 78 which is connected to it being deleted rather than 77 itself...

```
library(graph)

out <- read.csv("~/Downloads/adj/out.adjnoun_adjacency_adjacency", sep="")

out.network<-graph.data.frame(out,directed = FALSE)

x<-delete_vertices(out.network,c(77))

plot(x)
```

Why is this.. Am I making mistake

Comment: Pls edit your post and make it a reproducible example, e.g. `library(igraph);set.seed(1);g <- ba.game(20);coords <- layout.auto(g);par(mfrow=c(1,2));plot(g, layout=coords, vertex.label=V(g)$name);plot(delete.vertices(g, 5), layout=coords[-5,])
`. Which igraph Version?

Comment: `Error: ... cannot open file 'C:/Users/Rene/Downloads/adj/out.adjnoun_adjacency_adjacency': No such file or directory`

Comment: that was my local file...I imported using the option "import" in R

Comment: No one has the file, thus the error is not reproducible and the question is not as helpful as it could be. I showed you how to create a sample graph in my previous comment. In addition, you did not provide the igraph package version that you are using. I think in older versions, indexing begins at 0, whereas in newer versions it begins at 1. Might be wrong though

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure vertex `#78` gets deleted? `igraph` vertex indices are always continuous, so if you delete `#77` the former `#78` becomes the new `#77`, and the graph won't have `#78` any more. We can demonstrate this with a vertex attribute corresponding to the indices before the deletion. The example below verifies that the original vertex `#78` has the index `#77` after deleting `#77`:

```
library(igraph)

g <- barabasi.game(n = 78, m = 3)

V(g)$original_index <- seq(1:vcount(g))

V(g)$original_index

V(g)$original_index[77]
[1] 77

g <- delete.vertices(g, c(77))

V(g)$original_index[77]
[1] 78
```

Comment: Still not able to solve... The above code that you have given does not delete the vertex 77 as a whole. I can still see 77 when I plot the graph

Comment: That is not the original 77 but the original 78. You can easily check this by plotting with the original labels: `plot(g, vertex.label = V(g)$original_index)`. For further confirmation you can assign a unique color or check the connections, and you will see that the 77 after deletion is the original 78.

Answer (score 0):

this worked...

data1<-data1-V(data1)["23"]